# Change a ParticleEffect colour in a LibGDX game to a certain RGB value

Tags: colors, libgdx, rgb, effects, particles

I created a 2D particle effect with the Particle Editor tool that comes with LibGDX. Then, I needed to change the particle effect colour to a certain RGB colour programatically. For that purpose, I found this method:

myEffect.getEmitters().get(0).getTint().setColors(float [] colours);

My problem is that I don't know how to convert an RGB colour to the proper array values required by that method since I don't know exactly which colour format is used.

In the ParticleEditor, the colour selection format looks like HSV. However, the colour values stored in the resulting *.p file don't seem to match that format.

I wish someone could tell me how to do the conversion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **Javadocs**

```
public void setColors(float[] colors)
```

**Parameters**
colors - the r, g and b values for every timeline position

It takes the rgb values in float, There is an online convertor which takes HTML color (`HEX`) and convert them to `RGB` decimal values and then you can pass them inside your `setColors()` method.

Here is the link.

[Convertor](http://www.corecoding.com/utilities/rgb-or-hex-to-float.php)

Comment: I will at the very moment I have 15 reputation. I'm sorry, I created the account today :)

Comment: Up voting an answer needs 15 rep, but accepting takes none.:)

Comment: pe.getEmitters().first().getTint().setColors(new float[]{0.937f, 0.325f, 0.314f}); i am using this LOF where pe is ParticleEffect object, but i am getting errors.